# Connection Refused from Request Inside Docker

Tags: c#, docker

I have a relatively simple .net 8 asp net core setup: a web app and a separate webapi running in their own docker containers (just on my local machine). I can request both endpoints successfully in the browser, but am confused about how the app code should address the webapi via restsharp?

currently I get the following:

http:

> HttpRequestException: Connection refused

https:

> The SSL connection could not be established

Should the app refer to the webapi by hostname, IP, or "host.docker.internal" in combination with the port? I've tried all combinations so I'm confused on the correct way. Any advice / configuration / documentation suggestions would be appreciated.

My docker-compose.override.yml is:
version: '3.4'

```
services:
  demo-catalogue-api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8080
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8081
    ports:
      - "5001:8080"
      - "5002:8081"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/home/app/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/home/app/.aspnet/https:ro
  demo-webapp:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8080
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8081
    ports:
      - "6001:8080"
      - "6002:8081"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/home/app/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/home/app/.aspnet/https:ro
```

I've been referencing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/multi-container-applications-docker-compose and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port primarily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the webapp container, you can use `http://demo-catalogue-api:8080/` or `https://demo-catalogue-api:8081`.

I.e. you use the service name as the hostname and you use the unmapped ports.

If you connect to the API from an app running in a browser, then the requests come from outside the Docker network and you need to use the address of the host machine and the mapped ports.

I.e. if you're running it locally, you use `http://localhost:5001/` and `https://localhost:5002/`.

Comment: thanks Hans, that's what I had been trying. Investigating further, It looks like that hostname is actually resolving and my issue is an ssl cert for that address, not the hostname/traffic itself